# blocking any website from search results

Tags: google-search, search-engine

these days because Amazon rule the world, every time I put an Item in a search engine, the resulting million pages are all about how I can buy it from Amazon and everything related to it also to buy on Amazon... I am swamped, Amazon is useful don't get me wrong, I just want a click button choice after I put something in the search engine, I can redo it leaving out certain web sites... no to much to ask is it in the world of AI
thank you

Comment: start your search with `-site:amazon.com`